# How do I solve the equation $x^5 - 5x^4 - 5x^3 +25x^2 +4x -20 = 0$ given that its roots are of the form $+a, -a, +b, -b, c$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I understand that it is an easy problem, but I am not able to solve it at all! Any clue on how to approach this problem will be amazing! Thank you. (PS: I am just beginning to learn math).

Comment: Can you tell, by just looking at the equation, whether $1$ is a root or not? Start with that.

Comment: You can write this as $P(x) = (x - a)(x+a)(x-b)(x+b)(x-c)$ and assuming that $a,b,c$ are positive, then you might say that $1$ is either $a$ or $b$.

Comment: x^5-5x^4-5x^3+25x^2+4x-20=x^4(x-5)-5x^2(x-5)+4(x-5)=(x^4-5x^2+4)(x-5), now (x^4-5x^2+4)=(x^4-x^2-4x^2+4) or (x^4-4x^2-x^2+4)=(x^2-1)(x^2-4),we know that (x^2-1)=(x+1)(x-1) and (x^2-4)=(x+2)(x-2),so the answer will be: (x-5)(x+2)(x-2)(x+1)(x-1) where a=1,b=2,c=5

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(x)=x^5 - 5x^4 - 5x^3 +25x^2 +4x -20$.

Note a equation that would have $-a,a,-b,b,c$ as it's roots would be of the form $(x-a)(x+a)(x-b)(x+b)(x-c)=(x^2-a^2)(x^2-b^2)(x-c)$.

So we get

$$P(x)=x^5 - 5x^4 - 5x^3 +25x^2 +4x -20 = (x^2-a^2)(x^2-b^2)(x-c)=(x^4-(a^2+b^2)x^2+a^2b^2)(x-c)=x^5-cx^4+\dots$$

This tells us that $c=5$.

By polynomial division, if we divide $(x^5 - 5x^4 - 5x^3 +25x^2 +4x -20)$ by $(x-5)$, note that we get  $x^4-5x^2+4$.

However, note $$x^4-5x^2+4=(x^2)^2-5x^2+4=(x^2-1)(x^2-4)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x+2)$$

Comment: I think you might have an extra $x-5$ factor in the last line.

Comment: There is an extra $x-5$ in the second last line

Comment: @Airdish Is it right now?

Comment: Yes, it's fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use general theory of equations ie sum of root is $a-a+b-b+c=-(-5)=5$ thus $c=5$ then product of roots. Then summation of two roots grouped together... You have $c$ you have $4$ next equations to generate from there you can get $a,-a,b,-b$ or substitute $x$ as the value of roots. Add the equations of $a,-a$ you will get a quadratic after plugging $a^2=u$ which can also be done for $b$ as signs of odd powers will just cancel out after adding and you already know $c$ that's it.

Answer (score 0):

if you know that $a, -a, b, -b$ are roots then $(x^2 - a^2)(x^2-b^2)$ are factors.

however this is first thing that I see.

$$(x^5 - 5x^4) - 5(x^3-5x^2) + 4(x - 5) = 0$$